# equivalent of gl.readBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENTx) in webgl 1.0

Tags: webgl

i need to render to 2 textures (in on pass of course)

```
var extbuffers = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_draw_buffers');

var tex1 = gl.createTexture();  
//gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);  
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex1);  
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST); 
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, PVS, PVS, 0, gl.RGBA,gl.FLOAT,null);


var tex2 = gl.createTexture();
//gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE2);  
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex2);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, PVS, PVS, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);  



gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.createFramebuffer());
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex1, 0);  

gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, extbuffers.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_WEBGL, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex2, 0);

extbuffers.drawBuffersWEBGL(
// Here, we give it the list of slots we want to draw to.
[
    extbuffers.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL, // gl_FragData[0]
    extbuffers.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_WEBGL  // gl_FragData[1]
]
);
```

and the fragment shader :

```
#extension GL_EXT_draw_buffers : require

void main() {

                gl_FragData[0] = vec4(pos,vit);
                gl_FragData[1] = vec4(col,1.0);
}
```

but now is my problem : how can i read the textures ? I have readen some similar questions but about FramebufferRenderbuffer

i would like a :

```
gl.readBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
gl.readPixels(...);

gl.readBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
gl.readPixels(...);
```

Thanks.

EDIT : i use Webgl 1, but with *ad hoc* extension WEBGL_draw_buffers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create more framebuffers, attach the textures individually to those framebuffers, bind those framebuffers when you want to read from the textures.

Effectively

```
create texture1
create texture2

create drawFramebuffer
   attach texture1 as color attachment0
   attach texture2 as color attachment1

create readFramebuffer1
   attach texture1 as color attachment0

create readFramebuffer2
   attach texture2 as color attachment0
```

Now you bind `drawFramebuffer` when you want to draw, bind `readFrambuffer1` when you want to read from texture1 and bind `readFrameubffer2` when you want to read from texture2

Comment: it works  after that i put this :`ext.drawBuffersWEBGL( [ext.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL,ext.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_WEBGL]);`**before** create readFramebuffer1 and readFramebuffer2

Comment: FYI, drawBuffers are framebuffer state. unless no framebuffer is bound, then it's effectively canvas state. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/0vysktr8/) and [this](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html?exampleId=draw-cube-on-cube)